# Quick formatting error - PHP

Tags: php, formatting

```
 if (isset($_GET['z'])) {
 $file = $file ."-" ($_GET['z'];
 }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my formatting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (isset($_GET['z'])) {
      $file = $file . "-" . ($_GET['z']);
 }
```

you're missing one dot and one )

better one is

```
 if (isset($_GET['z'])) {
      $file .= "-" . $_GET['z'];
 }
```

Comment: $file .= '-' . $_GET['z'] would even be "better", provided that $file is what he expects it to be. :-)

Comment: @ninetwozero: yup, it's nicer :)